# BST fillArrary recursive function in c++

Tags: c++

Recursively fill an array using a recursive function level order transverse of a BST

```
template<class ItemType>
int BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::fillArray(ItemType arr[]) {
  BinaryNodeTree<ItemType> :: rootPtr;
  return fillArray(rootPtr);
  //return 0;
}

template<class ItemType>
int BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::fillArrayHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType> *subtreePtr,
    ItemType arr[], int pos) {
    if (subtreePtr == nullptr) {
      return 0;
    }
    // recursive call on left, add it, center, right.
    auto left = subtreePtr->getLeftChildPtr();
    auto right = subtreePtr->getRightChildPtr();
    int leftCount = 0;
    int rightCount = 0;
    int spot = 0;
    ItemType hold;
    if (subtreePtr->getLeftChildPtr() != nullptr) {
      hold = left->getLeftChildPtr->getItem();
      fillArrayHelper(left->getLeftChildPtr->getItem());
      arr[leftCount] = hold;
      leftCount++;
      return leftCount;
    }
    
  return 0;
} // end fillArrayHelper
```

What I have, I'm also getting an error with the scope res operator so I can't even test if this is working at all.

Comment: Please paste in the error text into the question so we can see and interpret exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: Also, it seems you haven't really thought this through, e.g. what is `rightCount` (supposed to be) used for? Shouldn't `fillArray` call `fillHelper`?

Comment: ./BinarySearchTree.cpp:153:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rootPtr'; did you mean 'rotate'?
  return fillArrayHelper(rootPtr);
                   ^~~~~~~
                   rotate
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1431:5: note: 'rotate' declared here
    rotate(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __middle,

Comment: I'm trying to use the return values to return how many items are added down the left, and right etc. I've only coded one side so far and haven't been able to test it as a result of a compile error too and I'm not honestly sure if that will work.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74540505/edit) and at that error to the question. It'll be easier to read when properly formatted, and everything necessary to answer the question should be in the question where it's permanent and easier to find.

Comment: And we'll need more context. What is `BinaryNodeTree<ItemType> :: rootPtr;` supposed to be? A variable definition?